# Add environment variables with PowerShell and bat files

Tags: powershell, batch-file, environment-variables

As part of a project, I need to run two bat files with a PowerShell script.  These bat files will perform several operations including the creation of environment variables.
But problem. The first environment variables are created (those created with the first bat file) but not the second ones (which must be created with the execution of the second bat file). The execution of the second one went "well" because the rest of the operations it has to perform are well done.

I use the same function for the execution of these .bat files.

```
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")
$argList = "/c '"$batFile'""
$process = Start-Process "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList $argList -Wait -PassThru -Verb runAd
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")
```

I use the line
`$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")`
to reload the environment variables. But that didn't solve the problem. Without this line I have the environment variables corresponding to the second bat file (the one running second) being created. With it, I have only those of the first one.

I also noticed that if I re-run my PowerShell program (so re-run the batch files), I had all the environment variables created.

Answer (score 0):

### Well 1st off:

It looks like you have an error in your code for executing your 2nd batch file so I suspect you re-wrote your code to go here and it's not at all in the original form, as how it's written you would never get anything further.

### You know what TL;DR: Try this

I've been writing a lot, and its a rabbit hole considering the snippet of code isn't enough of the process, the code is obviously re-written as it introduces a clearly different bug, and your description leaves something to be desired.

i'll leave some of the other points below re-ordered, and you can feel free to read/ignore whatever.

But here, is the long and short of it.

if you need to run this CMD scripts, and get some stuff out of them to ad to path, have them run normally and `echo` the `path` they create into stdout, then capture it in a powershell variable, dedupe it in powershell and set the path directly for your existing powershell environment.

Amend both of your `CMD Scripts` AKA `Batch Files` to add this to the very top before any existing lines.

```cmd
@(SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF )

CALL :ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_STARTS_HERE >NUL 2>NUL

ECHO=%PATH%

( ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B )

:ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_STARTS_HERE
REM All your original script lines should be present below this line!!
```

PowerShell code basically will be

```cmd
$batfile_1 = "C:\Admin\SE\Batfile_1.cmd"
$batfile_2 = "C:\Admin\SE\Batfile_2.cmd"
$Path_New = $($env:path) -split ";" | select -unique
$Path_New += $(&$batFile_1) -split ";" | ? {$_ -notin $Path_New}
$Path_New += $(&$batFile_2) -split ";" | ? {$_ -notin $Path_New}
$env:path = $($Path_New  | select -unique) -join ";"
```

Although if you don't need the separate testable steps you could make it more concise as:

```cmd
$batfile_1 = "C:\Admin\SE\Batfile_1.cmd"
$batfile_2 = "C:\Admin\SE\Batfile_2.cmd"
$env:path = $(
  $(  $env:path
      &$batFile_1
      &$batFile_2
  ) -split ";"  | select -unique
) -join ";"
```

---

Okay leaving the mostly done stuff where I quit-off trying to amend my points as I followed the rabbit hole tracking pieces around, as it will give some light on some aspects here

---

2nd off:  You do not need to `start-process` to run a CMD script, you can run a cmd script natively it will automatically instantiate a cmd instance.

`Start-Process` will spawn it as a separate process sure, but you wait for it, and although you use `-PassThru` and are saving that as a variable, you don't do anything with it to try to check it's status or error code so you may as well just run the CMD script directly and see it's `StdOut` in your powershell window, or save it in a variable to log it if needed.

3rd off:  Why not just set the environment variables directly using Powershell?

I'm guessing these scripts do other stuff but might be that you should just echo what they want to set Path to back to the PowerShell script and then dedupe it and set the path when done.

4th off: `$env:Path` is your current environment's path, this includes all pathtext that is from the `System` AND the `currentuser` profile (HKLM: and HKCU: registry keys for environment), while `$( [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") )` is your `System` (Local machine) pat has derived from your registry.

5th off:  The operational Environment is specific to each shell, when you start a new instance of `CMD /c` it inherits the environment of the previous `cmd` instance that spawned it.

6th off: Changes made to environmental variables do not 'persist' ie: you can't open a new `CMD` / `Powershell` instance and see them, and once you close that original `cmd` window they're gone, unless you edit the registry values of these items directoy or use `SET X` in a `cmd` session (Which is problematic and should be avoided!) and also ONLY affects the USER variables not the `system`/`local machine` variables.

Thus, any changes made to the environment in one `CMD` instance only operate within that existing `shell` unless they are changes that persist in the registry, in which case they will only affect new shells that are launched.

7th off: When you launch powershell, it is a cmd shell running powershell, and so powershell inherits whatever the local machine and current user's variables are at that moment when the interpreter is started.  This will be what is in `$env:xxx`

8th off: Setting `$env:Path = $([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine"))` will always change the current powershell environment to whatever is stored in the `[HKLM:\]` registry key for environmental variables.

Now given that we don't have all of your code and only a description of what is happening.

It appears you have one script Lets call it `batFile_1.cmd` that is setting some variables in your

For each batch file you run whether spawned implicitly or explicitly you will inherit the previous shell's command environment.

However

Each instance of CMD which you spawn with your batch files within them, spawns a separate cmd shell instance and he Instance of `CMD` that `powershell.exe` is running inside of, and thus your script was running in.

Now I'm just supposing what is happening since you only give a small snippet, which is not enough to actually reproduce your real issue.

But it seems like you spawn a cmd script,

So it's hard to know exactly is happening without the full context instead of the snippet, although I'll go into one scenario that might be happening below.

A note on Each CMD instance only inherits the values of it's parent.

(I feel this is much clearer to explain in opening an actual CMD window and test how the shell works by spawning another instance of CMD.

When the new instance is exited the variables revert to the previous instance because they only move from parent to child)

eg:

```cmd
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "a=hello"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo=%a%
hello

C:\WINDOWS\system32>CMD /V
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1082]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>(SET "a= there!"
More? SET "b=%a%!a!"
More? )

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo=%b%
hello there!

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo=%a%
 there!

C:\WINDOWS\system32>exit

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo=%a%
hello

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo=%b%
%b%

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

But that isn't really what is happening here you seem to be updating the command environment back to the Local machine